# Assign value to fhir.resource.servicerequest.ServiceRequest.status

Tags: python, hl7-fhir

I'm using fhir.resource python library.
I have a trouble when assign value to `status` parameter in ServiceRequest, it show error

> Traceback (most recent call last):
> File "D:\workspace\nar-fhir\main.py", line 5, in 
> sr.status = 'completed'
> File "pydantic\main.py", line 357, in pydantic.main.BaseModel.**setattr**
> pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 1 validation error for ServiceRequest
> **root** -> intent
> none is not an allowed value (type=type_error.none.not_allowed)

This is my code :

```
from fhir.resources.servicerequest import ServiceRequest
sr = ServiceRequest.construct()
sr.status = 'completed'
sr.intent = 'directive'
```

When I search ServiceRequest code, show like this :

```
intent: fhirtypes.Code = Field(
        None,
        alias="intent",
        title=(
            "proposal | plan | directive | order | original-order | reflex-order | "
            "filler-order | instance-order | option"
        ),
        description=(
            "Whether the request is a proposal, plan, an original order or a reflex"
            " order."
        ),
        # if property is element of this resource.
        element_property=True,
        element_required=True,
        # note: Enum values can be used in validation,
        # but use in your own responsibilities, read official FHIR documentation.
        enum_values=[
            "proposal",
            "plan",
            "directive",
            "order",
            "original-order",
            "reflex-order",
            "filler-order",
            "instance-order",
            "option",
        ],
    )
```

Any help?

Comment: Is the interface and code you're using aimed at FHIR R4?  'directive' was a late-breaking addition to R4, so it's possible that an older library wouldn't support it.  Other than that, no obvious issues with your code, though I'm not a Python person.  If you don't get a useful response after a couple of business days here, you could try on the [Python stream](https://chat.fhir.org/#narrow/stream/179218-python) on chat.fhir.org

Comment: But if we look at enum_values in the library, it has 'directive' option. 
Thank you for the suggestion.